# wkhtmltopdf shrink to fit page width

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.1 (I am on debian-jessie and that is the version I get with apt-get - I cannot instal anything that I do not get from apt-get).

I have a web page that looks like this:

[image]
And when converting to PDF it comes out looking like this:

[image]
I want the layout to be the same in the PDF. I have tried many, many, many different combination of options using --page-width and --zoom with a number < 1, but nothing makes the 2 tables and the image fit on the same row.

Anyone know how I can get the HTML to shrink to fit the page width?

Comment: Are you using a landscape format ?

Comment: No it's in portrait mode

Comment: So this behavior is pretty normal to me if your web view is responsive unless you apply a (big) --zoom < 1 and some margin-* 1mm.

Comment: What zoom would use use? I have tried as low as .1 and it seemed to have no affect.

Comment: Can you past here the command ?

Comment: I am not using any options at all other then --zoom.

Comment: Can you suggest any options I should use to make this work?

Comment: Here the arguments I use: `wkhtmltopdf --zoom 0.7 --margin-bottom "3mm" --margin-top "3mm" --margin-left "3mm" --margin-right "3mm"`


If it doesn't work you have to review the responsiveness of your document.

Comment: I ended up fixing this with CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately the web page got changed quite a bit and now I am back to square 1. I tried your args, but they did not help. Also tried updating to the new version of wkhtmltopdf and that made it even worse - entire sections of the page do not come out in the PDF with the new version. Now I have been messing with CSS for hours to no avail. This is a very unpleasant task.

Comment: I got through unpleasant tasks with wkhtmltopdf too. unfortunately it is very hard to debug without your sources. I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 by the way. And i'm not working with images so i can't tell about images behavior. If I had anything else that could help I would give it to you.

Comment: Upvoted for more visibility.